Issue with await request.formData() not responding in @remix-run/express adapter action
I created a project using the @remix-run/express adapter. Initially, I set up my register endpoint on the express side (/api/register).
I have integrated Zod and i18n into my Remix project as per the official documentation. While everything works fine outside of actions, when I try to use await request.formData() inside an action, it doesn't respond.
Initially, I tested this with Bun (using Elysia.js), but I suspected the issue might be related to Bun, so I moved the project to a Node.js environment. However, the same problem occurs, and in that case, the error is: 'ReadyableStream is locked'.
Here’s the relevant code:
    const createSchema = (t: TFunction) =>
      z.object({
        username: z.string().min(3, t("validation.usernameMin")),
        email: z.string().email(t("validation.invalidEmail")),
        password: z.string().min(6, t("validation.passwordMin")),
      });
    
    export const action: ActionFunction = async ({
      request,
    }: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
      console.log("register action");
      try {
        const t = await i18next.getFixedT(request);
        const schema = createSchema(t);
    
        const formData = await request.formData();
        console.log("formData", formData);
        const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
        console.log(data);
        schema.parse(data);
    
        return json({ success: true });
      } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof z.ZodError) {
          return json({ errors: error.errors }, { status: 400 });
        }
        return json({ errors: error?.toString() }, { status: 500 });
      }
    };

How can I resolve this issue with formData() inside the action function in both Bun and Node.js environments?

That seems odd. Have you tried calling request.formData() first before the other calls. You can only read the request body once, and I'm not sure what getFixedT is doing. Also, how are you submitting to this route? Is it a form, or some external POST request. Make sure it's sending the payload as application/x-www-form-urlencoded and not application/json
